# How do I manually trigger a hx-get event of an element from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, htmx

I am using [htmx](https://htmx.org/) to add some AJAX calls to my page. I have a `cart-count` element that is defined to retrieve the number of items in the cart 1s after the page is loaded:

```
<span id="cart-count" hx-get="/cart/count"
     hx-trigger="load delay:1s" hx-target="#cart-count" hx-swap="outerHTML">
</span>
```

I also have an `add-to-cart` button that, after its own stuff (e.g. change itself to `remove from cart` using htmx), send an extra attribute

```
    response['HX-Trigger-After-Swap'] = "cart-updated"
```

to the frontend (see [here](https://htmx.org/headers/x-hx-trigger/) for the doc).

I have an event listener that works,

```
document.body.addEventListener("cart-updated",
    function (evt) {
        alert("cart updated")
    })
```

but how can I trigger `hx-get` of the `#cart-count` element in JS?

Note that

```
hx-trigger="load delay:1s, cart-updated"
```

[would work](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/187) if the cart stuff is in the parent chain of `add-to-cart` element, but unfortunately this is not the case for my webpage.

Note that the question is also asked [here](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/339)

Comment: Doc link: https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/ To update another part of the page with the same response, we can also use: https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/ Also, we can listen for multiple events in the same hx-trigger: https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/

Answer (score 14):

You can listen for the event on the body of the document in the latest version of htmx using the `from:` modifier like so:

```
<span hx-get="/cart/count"
      hx-trigger="load delay:1s, cart-updated from:body" 
      hx-swap="outerHTML">
</span>
```

Note also that you don't need to use an explicit target here since the default target is the element that the `hx-get` is defined on.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you very much for posting this question and also @1cg for answering! :)

This htmx library is brilliant!

You can check how this server response hx-trigger with django works here:
https://github.com/ramiboutas/veryacademy_ecom

Basically when a user adds an item to the basket (or cart), you can pass in the response an event (in the example " updateBasketNumber") like in this view function

```
@require_http_methods(["PUT", "POST"])
def add_to_basket(request, product_id):
    basket = Basket(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    basket.add(product=product)
    response = render(request, 'store/basket/_addedbutton.html')
    trigger_client_event(response, "updateBasketNumber", { },)
    return response
```

in the html you can add this trigger event to get more info from the server (so you can update the number of items you have in the Basket or Cart):

```
<div id="basket-number" class="d-inline-flex" 
hx-get="{% url 'basket:update-number' %}" 
hx-trigger="load delay:0.5s, updateBasketNumber from:body">
{% include "store/basket/_number.html" %} 
</div>
```

I have implemented more  trigger events in the tutorial (originally from the Very Academy youtube channel; he uses ajax &js!), you can go to the github repo and check more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the JavaScript API could do the trick? I imagine with something like

```
document.body.addEventListener("cart-updated", function (evt) {
    const c = htmx.values(htmx.find("#cart-count"));
    htmx.ajax('GET', API_URI, { values: { "cart-count": c } })
})
```